# TypeError: a is null is displayed?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Google map auto completion is not working.  **Type Error: a is null** error is displayed.
Here is my code:

```
    <div class="input-wrapper">
      <input id="location" style="width: 350px;" class="location" type="text"
       value="<?php echo translate("Where_do_you_want_to_go"); ?>" name="location" 
       autocomplete="off" onblur="if (this.value == ''){this.value = '<?php echo translate("Where_do_you_want_to_go"); ?>'; }"
       onfocus="if (this.value == '<?php echo translate("Where_do_you_want_to_go"); ?>') {this.value = ''; }"
       placeholder="<?php echo translate("Where_do_you_want_to_go"); ?>">
      <p id="enter_location_error_message" class="bad" style="display:none;">&#10; Please set location&#10; </p>
</div>
```

This is my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  var input = document.getElementById('location');
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);    
  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {

  });
});
```

I tried to fix the issue.

Comment: There's nothing in your code calling a variable named `a`. What's your actual **HTML**? (Not your PHP - what it's compiling - right click -> view source)

Comment: I'm guessing at some point you're trying to use the map before initialising it (or not at all).

Comment: as far as I know google maps api will not work without google maps